# Anyone know the iOS custom scheme for Adobe Scan?

Tags: ios

Does anyone know what the iOS custom URL scheme for Adobe Scan iOS App?  For example the Adobe Reader scheme is com.adobe.adobe-reader://. I'm looking for the equivalent scheme so I can launch Adobe Scan from my app.

I've tried to randomly guess what the scheme is based on the known reader scheme.

UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "com.adobe.??????://")!)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

com.adobe.scan.ios
(from inspecting Info.plist)